# I don't know how to write dom document just once

Tags: javascript, dom

I would like rewrite a dom document just once.

Html:

```
<body>          

<form id="test">
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="30%">?</td>
<td>
<input name="q1" type="checkbox" id="q1" value="R"/>
R
<input name="q1" type="checkbox" id="q1" value="T"/>
T
<input name="q1" type="checkbox" id="q1" value="Ra"/>
Ra
<input name="q1" type="checkbox" id="q1" value="Ho"/>
Ho
<input name="q1" type="checkbox" id="q1" value="F"/>
F
<input name="q1" type="checkbox" id="q1" value="Fr"/>
Fr
<input name="q1" type="checkbox" id="q1" value="Fo"/>
Fo
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
<input name="submit" type="button" onClick="gradeTest()" value="Com"/>

</form> 
</body>
```

I tried with this:

```
function gradeTest() {
    var a1 = document.getElementsByName('q1');
    var a1answers = new Array();
    var a1right = new Array('R','T','Ra');
    var a1bool = true;

    for(i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        if(a1[i].checked) {
            a1answers.push(a1[i].value);
        }
    }
    a1answers.sort();
    a1right.sort();
    if(a1answers.length == a1right.length) {
        for(i = 0; i < a1answers.length; i++) {
            if(a1answers[i] != a1right[i]) {
                a1bool = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        a1bool = false;
    }
    if(a1bool == true) {
        var moveable = document.getElementById('test');
        var s = '<p align="center"> <img border=0 src="arbol.png" width="250" /></p>'; 
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = s;
        var elements = div.firstChild;  
        document.body.appendChild(elements);

        var newParent = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('test'));
        newParent.removeChild(newParent.firstChild);
        newParent.insertBefore(moveable, newParent.firstChild);
        correctAnswers++;
    }
}
```

When I execute this code, print a lot of images, but i want one.

In the line 6, i put test whiout test didn't work

Thank you

Comment: What is `document.createElement('test')` supposed to mean? There's no such thing as a `<test>` element.

Comment: Since your first line contains `document.getElementById` can you provide the HTML?

Comment: `appendChild` returns the child, not the parent. `newParent` doesn't have any children, so `newParent.removeChild(newParent.firstChild))` won't do anything.

Comment: I don't see any way this can create multiple images, unless it's in a loop that you haven't shown.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. You can use a [Stack Snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0) to put an executable example in the question.

Comment: document.createElement('test') , is a test, i dont know if this is ok. I added the html. and removeChlid doesnt work @Barmar

Comment: Clicking on that button will submit the form, which reloads the page. You won't see any of the changes to the DOM.

Comment: "removeChild doesn't work". What is it supposed to remove? Like I said above, the new element doesn't have any children.

Comment: I try to explain, I would like when the first a1bool == true, insert the picture arbol.png, but if a1bool remains true, i dont want insert anything (for that removeChild), @Barmar. Thank you mate

Comment: You cannot have multiple nodes with the same `id` tag and the same `name` tag...

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you've already appended the new element, and don't add it again.

```
if(a1bool == true) {
    if (!document.getElementById("arbol")) {
        var s = '<p align="center" id="arbol"> <img border=0 src="arbol.png" width="250" /></p>'; 
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = s;
        var elements = div.firstChild;  
        document.body.appendChild(elements);
    }
    correctAnswers++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work, moveable.firstChild.className always is different to arbol @Barmar

Comment: Sorry, I got confused about where you were appending the image. I've changed my answer to give the new element an ID and check for that.

Comment: I try to clarify, suppose you need to rewrite html document with dom, and you insert this: document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('OK'));, but you want inser just once this. you want see OK, but no OKOKOKOK, I put the example with one image, but is the same @Barmar